# updating and searching mysql set using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, set, where-clause

I have a column in table which has possible values of tom,john,jerry`(SET)`. I have a variable that a user enter and I store it in `$var` and want that at some point. I could check that if the value in $var exists in particular row then don't update else update, How I can do this in PHP.
I have several rows like `tom,john`

```
    john,jerry
```

I dont want `tom,john,tom`

Comment: Have you read [the documentation on the `SET` column type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set.html)? Apparently not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one suggestion.

Please change the database values so that you have: `,tom,john,tom,` (Notice the appending and preceding commas `,`.

Now if you want to search for `tom`, fire an SQL like:

```
SELECT id FROM DB_TBL WHERE field LIKE '%,$val,%'
```

Repeat this for all values user has entered OR put in a single text box with commas.

Hope this works.